# Print type of loaded beans along with name

Tags: java, spring

How can I print the type of all the spring beans that are loaded. I can print the bean name using ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames(). Is there a way to print the type pertinent to each bean? For eg: If Bean B extends Bean A , I want type Bean A to be printed against Bean B as it extends A.

Comment: Why should it print `Bean A` instead of `Bean B`? If the type is `B`, why show its superclass as the type?

Comment: I wanted to see if the class is indeed extending another class.

Comment: You can retrieve the bean and use reflection on its `Class` to find out a lot about the object.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman for the suggestion. I tried a different approach - ctx.getBeansOfType(ParentInterceptor.class). This returns all the bean of type ParentInterceptor.

Comment: If you wanted to know the beans that are `ParentInterceptor` or its subclasses, why didn't you ask it in the question instead of talking about a completely different situation?

Comment: Sorry , I wanted to fetch all the beans and identify their parent type. But I did not find an option from applicationContext. But I saw that it had this method , which returned  the subclasses. Thanks for helping me.